# Blackboard bold letters

Tags: blackboard

This is a very short question : how do I produce the blackboard bold letters in the second column (the one that reads "Text") of this [document](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/mathpackages/dsfont-symbols.pdf)? It seems to me that the package `eulervm` uses the same blackboard bold as the standard math font in Latex, and I would like to replace the standard blackboard bold with that of the linked document.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplx}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
I want the blackboard bold letters from the \textit{second} column.
$\mathbb{ABCDEFG}\mathds{ABCDEFG}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: that is the package documentation for a package called dsfont (so it says in the page you reference, so add `\usepackage{dsfont}` then use the latex commands shown in the table

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When I use the `dsfont` package (by adding `\usepackage{dsfont}` in the preamble), the blackboard bold letters I get in the document correspond to that of the _third_ column. I don't know how to get those of the second column.

Comment: You've been on the site long enough to know that _every_ question should have a complete small document that shows the problem: please edit the question:-)

Comment: `\usepackage[sans]{dsfont}` (which are not those in the left column, those of the first column resemble the `\mathbb` from `fourier` package).

Comment: @Manuel when I use the sans option for the package, I gt a different result.

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/doublestroke for the documentation?

Comment: `\mathds{ABC}` according to the documentation? The `sans` option causes `\mathds` to use a different alphabet.

Comment: the document you reference uses xits-math fonts for comparison to dsfonts so presumably you want `\mathbb` from `xits-math`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle @Manuel How can I use only the blackboard bold from some package, while using `eulervm` for the rest?

Comment: [Look here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/mathalfa.pdf)

Comment: You can examine the [source](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/mathpackages/dsfont-symbols.tex) of the PDF you linked to see how the symbols are created. However, I think you will need to use XeTeX/LuaTeX, though I'm not certain - maybe there is an alternative for TeX.

Comment: @Manuel thanks, this seems to be what I need, however, it seems not to work with `eulervm`...

Comment: Did you try loading it before `eulervm`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{pplx}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[bb=boondox]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
I want the blackboard bold letters from the \emph{second} column.
$\mathbb{ABCDEFG}$
\end{document}
```

Instead of `boondox` you could use `fourier`, or `esstix`.

[image]

Comment: This does it! Do you have any idea why it doesn't work with `mathpi`?

Comment: `mathpi` is not free; of course, is not installed by default (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 5):

Example from the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/doublestroke/dsdoc.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\[\mathds{N}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}\]
\[\mathds{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: serif doublestroke]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sans]{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\[\mathds{N}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}\]
\[\mathds{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: sans doublestroke]

Comment: Take a look at the comment section, I want a different blackboard bold.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Indeed. But that was not clear when I posted this.