# Which blackboard font is used?

Tags: pdftex

[image]

Can anyone help me in knowing which mathbb font is being used here and how to use it?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201339/116936) : with `\usepackage[sans]{dsfont}`, `$\mathds{ZQ}$`.

Comment: @marsupilam Very nice. Thanks :) Would care to write this as an answer??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two : `Q` and `Z` look like those from the `dsfont` package with the `sans` option.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[sans]{dsfont}
\begin{document}
$\mathds{ZQ}$
\end{document}
```